# Does flagging a review audit as duplicate penalize me?

Tags: support, review, duplicate-questions, review-audits

I just had a [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2854972) of a First Question.

It had flawless form, but I thought it must have been asked before.
So I searched and found the exact question.

I upvoted it, and not flagged it, out of fear for temporarily being denied access to the mostly empty review queue.

Would I have been penalized if I was to flag it as a duplicate?

Comment: This is one of the things that the review audit fails to cover.